# Where can I find shell script for parse JSON on busybox?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, json

I have an IP camera with armv5tejl architecture. There I have busybox. I have to be able to parse JSON responses from curl. The problem is that I don't have programs like:
jq, jshon, jsawk...
It is hard to instal them for this architecture. I have to find some shell script which can parse JSON object and JSON array. 
If it is possible to find this script, please, show me that script

Comment: what about perl?

Comment: Don't have neither perl nor python. I have to find some solution with awk, sed, grep and so on..

Comment: jq should not be hard to compile from source, it only needs bison and flex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have ash or bash so you can use [json.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh). You have awk so you can use [json.awk](https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk).

Comment: Yes. Thank you for help. I have found json.awk just several minutes ago)

Comment: json.sh also works with ash

Answer (score 2):

As grochmal said. There is jq which is pretty good but I couldn't compile it.
Also we can just use [JSON.awk](https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk) to parse json (is not very convenient but works).
Example:

```
echo -e jsonFile | awk -f JSON.awk
```

To get necessary keys and values we can grep output. Example (parse json response with google drive folders to find all ids of folders):

```
echo -e jsonResponse | awk -f JSON.awk | egrep '\["items",[0-9]+,"id"\]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure the best way today in 2023  to parse json in busybox (and when you CANNOT install foreign programs) is to use function from [JSON.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh)

Parsing is quiete slow when curl return a big and complex json (more than 80 kb) but I'm working on to make it faster... if you're interested, follow on the github.com project

And as this post is years old, I'm posting today to confirm that in 2023 and after a long search and a lot of  tests, I did not find any better bash only json parsing library (It handle nearly all cases of stranges characters, strings... you can encountered in a reply of curl which is a json formatted string), so it work in nearly all cases.